# jQuery hover div and addClass to another div

Tags: jquery, html

HTML Structure:

```
<div class="alpha">
// something goes here

<div class="beta"></div>

</div>
```

When I hover the div "beta", a class added to div "alpha"..

I'm using jQuery addClass/removeClass.

```
jQuery('.beta').hover(
function(){$(".alpha").addClass('hover')},
function(){$(".alpha").removeClass('hover')});
```

NOTE: Here I have more than one div's (alpha divs) so when I use the jQuery above, the class added to other divs too, but I want to add the class to only that div which is hover :)

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the structure is always the same as your example I would go with .parent() function.

```
$('.beta').hover(function(){
   $(this).parent().toggleClass('hover');
});
```

This way you don't need to specify the alpha class and atleast the script is a bit shorter :P

[Here's a fiddle for you](http://jsfiddle.net/N5BEf/)

If your structure changes but .alpha still stays as a "master" parent you can specify

```
$(this).parent(".alpha").toggleClass('hover');
```

Comment: waooow thats great :) it works :) but if we modify our code a bit.

<code> 

`
<div class="main">
<div class="alpha">abc</div>
<div class="beta">xyz</div>
<div>`

same case, when hover to beta, class apply to alpha div.

Comment: Yep, as long as the .beta is a child of an .alpha this'll work. If you add some other div as a parent to .beta, ie. <div class="alpha">abc</div><div class="gamma"><div class="beta">xyz</div> </div><div>, you'll need to specify the ".alpha" for the .parent() function. But if this solved the problem you can mark this as an answer and I don't mind if you give it a +1 :)

Comment: yeah sure :) please take a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/EQ7Ny/ ..

here I want to burr only alpha div.

Comment: Oh I misread your comment. In this case, since the .beta is no longer a child of .alpha, the .parent() function wont work and you need to use the .closest() function. You can use .siblings() function here. Here's a updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EQ7Ny/1/

Comment: But if you have multiple .alpha&.beta divs in the .main div this wont work either because it will add the .hover class to all the .alpha divs. I'd recommend giving each .alpha&.beta combination some wrapper so that there's only one of each in it, ie. <div class="main"><div class="wrap"><div class="alpha">alpha div</div><div class="beta">beta div</div></div></div>. And btw, you should be more accurate on your questions when writing it here, because this case is nothing like your original post.

Comment: thankyou sooo much :) It works man :) it got what i need :) :D thankyou alot (y)

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the `$(this)` reference inside the hover function, and after that use .closest() to target the required element. i.e] element with the class `.alpha`

```
jQuery('.beta').hover(function(){
   $(this).closest(".alpha").addClass('hover')
},function(){
   $(this).closest(".alpha").removeClass('hover');
});
```

Comment: thanks for your help but I'm afraid I'm not able to get the result :( when I use your method, nothing happens, but if I remove " (this).closest " from the code, It works as it before.

Comment: @Sohaib can you make a demo of it..?

Comment: please take a look at this jsfiddle.net/EQ7Ny .. here I want to burr only alpha div.

Comment: @Sohaib you have confused us by providing a wrong html structure.. :) ok any way carry on.

Comment: Aravindasam - actually the time I posted, the html structure was like that :) thanks for your reply. I really appreciate your help. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `$(this).closest('.alpha')` to relate it to the hovered element. You can also shorten your code by using `toggleClass`:

```
jQuery('.beta').hover(function(){
    $(this).closest(".alpha").toggleClass('hover');
}};
```

Comment: thanks for your help but I'm afraid I'm not able to get the result :( when I use your method, nothing happens, but if I remove " (this).closest " from the code, It works as it before.